# Can't assign values to properties of object with a "for...in" loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

Here's my object:

```
var cornersAbs = {
    topLeftCorner: { x: center.x + orin.corners.topLeft.x, y: center.y + orin.corners.topLeft.y, OOB: false },
    topRightCorner: { x: center.x + orin.corners.topRight.x, y: center.y + orin.corners.topRight.y, OOB: false },
    bottomLeftCorner: { x: center.x + orin.corners.bottomLeft.x, y: center.y + orin.corners.bottomLeft.y, OOB: false },
    bottomRightCorner:{ x: center.x + orin.corners.bottomRight.x, y: center.y + orin.corners.bottomRight.y, OOB: false }
}
```

And my loop

```
for (var corner in cornersAbs) {
    corner.OOB = corner.x < 0 | corner.y < 0 | corner.x > canvas.width | corner.y > canvas.height;
}
```

doesn't seem to be assigning any values to the corner.OOB properties.

Nothing seems to help, even if I write the loop like so:

```
for (var corner in cornersAbs) {
    cornersAbs.corner.OOB = cornersAbs.corner.x < 0 | cornersAbs.corner.y < 0 | cornersAbs.corner.x > canvas.width | cornersAbs.corner.y > canvas.height;
}
```

(I tried writing it this way because console.log(corner) for each iteration would print "topLeftCorner", "topRightCorner", etc. instead of "cornersAbs.topLeftCorner," etc. Writing the loop this way, however, gives me an error saying that cornersAbs.corner is undefined.)

Using bracket notation doesn't help either.

When I print the value of any corner.OOB the console prints "false" (the value I initalize each corner.OOB to) or "undefined."

I've tested the positions I'm reading into corner.x and corner.y, they are working fine.

Comment: It says here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in that the object doesn't need to be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do:

```
cornersAbs[corner]=...
```

to access the 'corner' you are looking at.

To see a sub-property, you use `cornerAbs[corner].prop`, which indexes the property referred to by corners and looks at `prop` within it.

On the other hand, `cornerAbs.corner` is equivalent to `cornerAbs["corner"]`, which is not what you want.

Comment: You might want to explain that `corner` is just the property name so you need to use `cornerAbs[corner]` to access the actual property value.  A little explanation about "why" makes an answer much better.

Comment: cornersAbs[corner].OOB = ... does the trick. Thank you EyasSH. Although I'm not sure why either full dot notation or full bracket notation did not work.

Comment: @jfriend00 I mentioned that I tried EyasSH's method already (using the full name of the property) but it didn't work for me because I used full bracket notation (cornersAbs[corner][OOB]) or full dot notation (cornersAbs.corner.OOB). Still not sure why I have to use a mish-mash of notation.

Comment: @Ben - You need `cornersAbs[corner].OOB` or `cornersAbs[corner]["OOB"]`.  What goes in the brackets is a literal string or a variable name that contains a string.  Since `corner` is a variable containing a string, you have to use brackets for that one.  Since `OOB` is a literal string, you can use either for that part of the reference.  You can't use `cornersAbs[corner][OOB]` because `OOB` is not a defined variable.

Comment: Thanks. Makes perfect sense now.